# How to configure a pre-created Kafka topic as a sink in kafka-connect?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I am trying to sink a postgreql DB (which is the source) events logs to a kafka confluent cloud already created and configured topic.

FYI, I am using `quay.io/debezium/connect:1.9` docker image as my kafka connect server, an aws RDS postgresql database as a source and a kafka confluent cloud topic as a sink.

I know that there is parameters like `CONNECT_TOPIC_CREATION_ENABLE=false` = `topic.creation.enable: false` in properties that could prevent the auto creation of kafka topic (since its not allowed in my confluent cloud broker) but where do I specify the topic destination name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Debezium, the topic is determined from a concatenation of the server, database schema, and table name.

> For example, suppose that `fulfillment` is the logical server name in the configuration for a connector that is capturing changes in a PostgreSQL installation that has a `postgres` database and an `inventory` schema that contains four tables: `products`, `products_on_hand`, `customers`, and `orders`. The connector would stream records to these four Kafka topics:
>
> - fulfillment.inventory.products
> - fulfillment.inventory.products_on_hand
> - fulfillment.inventory.customers
> - fulfillment.inventory.orders

https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/connectors/postgresql.html#postgresql-topic-names

To further manipulate the topic name from the Connector, you can use [RegexRouter](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/transforms/regexrouter.html) transform. For example, if you wanted to remove the logical server name "prefix" from each topic, or only extract the table name directly. You can also completely override the topic name with a static value, as you are asking for.

---

`CONNECT_TOPIC_CREATION_ENABLE` is not directly related to Debezium. It is a general property for Kafka Connect.

> Whether to allow automatic creation of topics used by source connectors, when source connectors are configured with `topic.creation.` properties

https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#connectconfigs_topic.creation.enable

Comment: Hi @oneCricketeer, thanks for your answer. Yeah I know this story of concatenation, but, I don't want to use auto created topic based on table or db name, I want to write the events of all tables into one single pre-created topic... I am currently looking on the side of `database.history.kafka.topic` connector config

Comment: The history topic config isn't what you want. You can use RegexRouter transform to completely overwrite the topic name created by Debezium and write to your own.

Comment: waw interresting, I have seen this in the doc but was not sure that this was it since it doesnt look that simple at first ! it was bizarre, anyway I will look at how it works, if you have hints do not hesitate man, thank you for this

Comment: IT WORKED with the transform thing ! update you answer so I can validate it :p thanks